# how to get a fullscreen modal from within an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe, modal-dialog

I was wondering if it's possible to call a modal from within an iframe and view it in fullscreen mode.

I made a try with jquery.ui.modal but the modal remains into the iframe area.

Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A jQuery "modal dialog" is just a `div` on the page, above the other elements, generally with a semi-transparent background, that fills the entire page. An i-frame has constrained proportions. You can't do this - for the same reason you can't make a modal dialog that takes up more space on the screen than the browser window.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamClark, I know about a "modal window", but is there not a way to reference parent.window, so the modal is not confined to the iframe area?.

Comment: Why not duplicate the content on the parent window, or create it on the fly ? use the `top.window....`

Comment: @bobighorus: you could possibly get the parent page to display the dialog, but it would need to be in the same domain as the iframe to get around XSS security rules. Also, it would probably be easier to have some script on the parent page to execute the request.

Answer (score 0):

It would a great help if you post your code, but you can do a simple modal with this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/cEq69/

In jsFiddle is NOT working, may be due to it is wrong or may be because jsfiddle is blocking the window.parent property via server code, but the property window.parent should do the trick if I am not missing something.

Regards!

In fact, the code from jsFiddle allows me to do window.parent.parent but has no effect either